# how to apply add-migration and update-database command in webapi when it shows some error?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to add-migration with the name Initial and when i update the database it shows some error, so how can i resolve that error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8fQ0.png)
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Books_BooksCovers_BookCoverId' on table 'Books' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index.

i want to update-database and add table in the database

Answer (score 0):

I understand that when creating a foreign key constraint, you may have concerns about data deletion or updates causing cascading effects. That's why you have the option to set the ON DELETE and ON UPDATE actions. By selecting NO ACTION, you can prevent any automatic cascading actions from occurring when a referenced record is deleted or updated. This is a great way to keep your data consistent and avoid any unintended consequences.